# How can i add UIViewController after splash screen in phonegap project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, uiviewcontroller

i have created one phonegap ios project.In that currently after splash screen it loading a index.html file. I like to add one introduction viewcontroller like below image after splash screen and user have an option to close introduction viewcontroller so they can see the index.html file.

Is there anyway to add UIViewController file before loading index.html ??

eg: SPLASH SCREEN --> INTRODUCTION VIEWCONTROLLER --> INDEX.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Classes >> AppDelegate.m file replace didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function with this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
self.window.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;      
UIViewController *myController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];    
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.viewController.view.frame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
myController.view = myView;    
UINavigationController *myNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myController];

UIBarButtonItem *leftButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancel)];   
myController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton;   
self.window.rootViewController = myNav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

 return YES;
}

-(void)cancel{
  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what will happen if i added this?

Comment: According SPLASH SCREEN --> INTRODUCTION VIEWCONTROLLER --> INDEX.html after splash screen load this custom viewcontroller there is on cancel button on left side , you do the action with this button after load index.html file